# PHPUnit can't find PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase. What package is missing?

Tags: php, phpunit

I installed phpunit with all dependencies:

```
pear install -a phpunit/phpunit
```

When I run a test with a failed assertion it complains it can't find PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

The package you are missing is `pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_Story` as you can find [on the pear repository page](http://pear.phpunit.de/) and [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-story).

PS: I found this by typing the class name into google.

Comment: This is the top story for PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase =P

Answer (score 2):

PEAR installation has been [deprecated](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method), currently is better to use Composer for it, here is the PHPUnit [installation guide](http://phpunit-doc.verber.kh.ua/3.7/en/installation.html) just adding bellow lines

```
 "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*",
    "phpunit/php-invoker": "*",
    "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*"
  }
```

or better`sudo composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=4.3.*'`

Comment: `"phpunit/phpunit-story": "*"` is repeated twice, it is also the only line I needed to resolve this error. (Don't forget to `composer update`)

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten same errors in Yii framework.

Solved it by:

1) using phpunit.phar installation([Installing PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html));

2) manually added [TestCase class](https://github.com/phpunit/phpunit-story/tree/master) into "autoloader" - ../tests/bootstrap.php :

`if (file_exists(_YII_FRAMEWORK_PATH_.'test/PHPUnit/Extensions/Story/TestCase.php')){
  require_once(_YII_FRAMEWORK_PATH_.'test/PHPUnit/Extensions/Story/TestCase.php');
}`