# PHPUnit Extension warning in Yii

Tags: unit-testing, yii, warnings

I am setting up unit testing to work with the Yii framework. Apart from Yii, my PHPUnit works great. But along with Yii when I try to test it, it gives me the following warning every time.

```
Warning: include(PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php): failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii1112\framework\YiiBase.php on li
ne 423

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php' for i
nclusion (include_path='.;D:\xampp\htdocs\sms_dev\protected\extensions\yii-mail;
D:\xampp\htdocs\sms_dev\protected\extensions\giix-components;D:\xampp\htdocs\sms
_dev\protected\components;D:\xampp\htdocs\sms_dev\protected\models;D:\xampp\php\
PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii1112\framework\YiiBase.php on line 423
```

I have searched a lot and have also asked in the Yii forum, but nothing seems to be working out.

Does anyone have any idea what this warning means? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Does the directory where it is referring to has the requested file?

Comment: Which test gives you the error?

Comment: No, the file is missing from the reference.

Comment: any test gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4):

The file `PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php` is part of the package `PHPUnit_Story`, which can be installed with:

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
```

See also: [PHPUnit can't find PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase. What package is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977235/phpunit-cant-find-phpunit-extensions-story-testcase-what-package-is-missing)

Answer (score 0):

The protected/tests directory is not in your include path. I would suggest moving your protected directory from any public location, and just add the protected folder to the include path. so `d:\xampp\htdocs\sms_dev\protected\` instead of listing each directory seperately.

Either this is the problem or the file doesn't exist and you have to check your code.

Answer (score 0):

With pear install dependencies [ **Now pear packages are not updated better install with composer** ]

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_Selenium
```

**Better if you install phpunit with composer these errors will not come**

step 1:
Create a composer.json file in your project root:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.4",
        "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src"}
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

step 2:
Install composer into your project using:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ensure composer is executable:

```
chmod +x composer.phar
```

Let composer install the dependencies:

```
./composer.phar install --dev
```

Check you have a project specific phpunit version installed:

```
bin/phpunit --version
```

the above specified  is a softlink

```
ls -la bin/phpunit
bin/phpunit -> ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Afterwords you can make softlink of  'phpunit' from vendor directory into directory of php in use. 
This will remove all warnings related to

```
PHP Warning:  include(classes/PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php)
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'classes/PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php' 
PHP Warning:  include(classes/Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader.php)
```